# How to get the value of json field when its parent object key is dynamic using a jq expression?

Tags: jq

Example json:

```
{
  "a": 1,
  "c": {
    "ca": 1.1
  },
  "d": {},
  "e": [1,2,3],
  "f": [
    {
      "fa": "vf1",
      "fb": "vf2",
      "fc": [],
      "fffs232/232": {
        "z": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "fa": "vf3",
      "fb": "vf4",
      "fc": [1.1,2.3],
      "fffs232/232": {
        "z": 2
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I want a full path jq expression that gives me the values of "z". Such expression should not explicitly mention  "fffs232/232" since that key is dynamic.

Is this possible with jq?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want the path to z or  the value of z?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `..`, e.g. along the lines of:

```
jq '.. | objects | .z // empty'
```

If `.z` can take the value `null`, then adjust according to your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

If the name is dynamic but the position is known, you can iterate over field candidates using `.[]` and check if a subfield "z" exists using `select` and `has`:

```bash
.f[][] | select(has("z")?).z
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/EQaS8WHBQkU)

Alternatively, if the depths are also unknown, you can traverse the whole document using `..`:

```bash
.. | select(has("z")?).z
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/NKow2v1Ipll)